# Looping through components in angular

Tags: angular, typescript, api, loops, get

I have multiple angular components within a display:flex div container. I receive datatable from API which has as much rows as I have components. Each row is data for the component. Component has @Input which corresponds to data row.
I want to have a loop which does this pseudocode:

```
For i=0 to container.children.count-1{
    cast(container.children[i] as mycomponent).Input=datatable.row[i]
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can mark your child with # and get it with @ViewChildren annotation

HTML:

```
<child #ChildRef></child>
<child #ChildRef></child>
<child #ChildRef></child>
```

TS:

```
@ViewChildren('childRef') childRefs;
getChilds = () => {
  return this.childRefs.toArray();
}
```

Another approach, more cleaner / event driven:

> What you also can do it's to create a service, inject in parent and
> child component, the components subscribes to the service and you can
> notify the children to update their values, the parent emits the update event.

NgModel way:

https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding

> Use TwoWayDataBinding [(ngModel)]="ObjectRef"

Comment: I will use two way binding. Thank you.

Comment: Don't forget to accept my answer, when it resolves your question ;-)